# Dismiss ImagePicker before completion

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using ImagePickerSheetController in Swift. My code looks like this

```
 controller.addAction(ImagePickerAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Take Photo", comment: "Action Title"), secondaryTitle: NSLocalizedString("Use this photo", comment: "Action Title"), handler: { _ in

  presentImagePickerController(.Camera)

  }, secondaryHandler:
  { _, numberOfPhotos in

  self.getAssetThumbnail(self.controller.selectedImageAssets.last!)
  self.performImageRecognition(scaledImage)
  }))
```

My problem is: the ImagePicker get's dismissed after 10 seconds after the user chooses an image, which gives the idea the app has frozen. The reason for this is that the second method `performImageRecognition` uses OCR so it takes a while.

I want to dismiss the controller before the function is completed, but how am I able to do so? I could just add an ActivityIndicator but I rather like dismissing the imagePickerController.

Anyone has an idea how to do this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since your OCR method is a heavy task - it should be invoked after pick has finished. One line after the other doesn't necessarily guarantee that since OS executes in nano scale. 
Why not Implementing Delegate Methods of UIImagePickerController? Thus, you can put your code on the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo and do there the OCR stuff and also dismiss the picker yourself.
For Instance:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
if let pickedImg = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage 
{
    // use your pickedImg
}

dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

// do your OCR stuff here...}
```

Don't forget `picker.delegate = self`

Good Luck

Comment: Actually, I tried with the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. Since the custom UIImagePicker I'm using doesn't call this method, this is useless.. Thanks for your help though!